# Exclude "|" from regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to exclude "|" from a list of youtube tags.

[image]

So far I am able to regex select all the tags that is cute for example in the below string

`cute|"cute nail art"|"cute"|"cute"|"fcute"`

I am able to highlight "cute" and cute| exactly. The problem is the "|". How do I get rid of it?

My regex query is this `("\bcute\b")|(\bcute\b[^\s])`.

My expected outcome is to highlight the cute and "cute".

Any tips would be appreciated and thank you for reading.

Comment: What is your expected outcome?

Comment: The input looks like CSV with `|` used as separator instead of comma. What language do you use?

Comment: @axiac , updated my question to include the outcome. The outcome I expect the highlighting of the word `cute` as well as `"cute"`.

Comment: @axiac The string value is just formatted to be separated by `|` e.g. `bag|"lace"|"bug"`

Comment: Your intention is not clear to me. Given the input string `cute|"cute nail art"|"cute"|"cute"|"fcute"`, what exactly do you want? Do you want to find the occurrences of `cute` (as is or quoted) and mark them somehow? Like `<cute>|"cute nail art"|<"cute">|<"cute">|"fcute"`?

Comment: Depending on the language you use there may be better ways. Not necessarily faster or using less code but safer. Regular expression sometimes match less or more than you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input is a string of tags joined by `|` and some tags are enclosed in quotes, and you want to identify and mark somehow a certain tag, both as is and quoted, the regular expression you need could look like this:

```
(?<=\||^)(cute|"cute")(?=\||$)
```

Check it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/acjM8R/3

#### The regex explained

```
(?<=        # start a positive lookbehind assertion
  ^         # match the beginning of the string
  |         # OR
  \|        # match the character '|' literally (it has a special meaning when not escaped)
)           # end of the lookbehind assertion
(           # start a capturing group; it is also used to group the alternatives
  cute      # match the word 'cute' (the tag) as is
  |         # OR
  "cute"    # match the word "cute" (the tag) when it is quoted
)           # end of the group
(?=         # start a positive lookahead assertion
  \|        # match the character '|' literally (it has a special meaning when not escaped)
  |         # OR
  $         # match the end of the string
)           # end of the lookahead assertion
```

The fragment `^|\|` matches either the start of the string (`^`) or the character `|` (the separator). Similar, the fragment `\||$` matches either a `|` (the separator) or the end of the string.

A positive assertion is a test on the characters preceding (`(?<= ... )`) or following (`(?= ... )`) the current matching point that does not actually consume any characters.

All in all, the regex above matches either `cute` or `"cute"` but only when it is surrounded by the delimiter `|` or by the string boundaries.

#### Update

A different way to write `(cute|"cute")` is `(("?)cute\2)`.

The fragment `("?)` captures an optional (`?`) quote (`"`). It is followed by the actual tag. The fragment `\2` means *"the same as the second capture group"* which, in this case, is the text matched by `("?)`.

This means that if `("?)` matches something (a quote), `\2` also must match a quote. If `("?)` matches an empty string (there is no quote between `|` and `cute`), `\2` also matches an empty string.

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/acjM8R/4/

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you are tying to do is use a literal `|`. Therefore you need to escape it like `\|`.